# How to return empty abstract class data set (PostgreSQLResult)?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to rewrite my code to make is null safety.

```
  PostgreSQLResult getResultFromCache(sqlQuery) {
    for (var req in requestsCacheList) {
      if(req.requestHash == sqlQuery.hashCode) {
        return req.requestResult;
      }
    }
    // var p = PostgreSQLResult(); // what should be here? Implementing PostgreSQLResult?
    // return p;
  }
```

I should to return here `PostgreSQLResult` instead of `null`. I looked [sources](https://github.com/stablekernel/postgresql-dart/blob/fdad1605c1994d3a708b064673b4aea67463b5ff/lib/src/execution_context.dart#L117) what `PostgreSQLResult` is:

```
/// A single row of a query result.
///
/// Column values can be accessed through the `[]` operator.
abstract class PostgreSQLResultRow implements List {
  List<ColumnDescription> get columnDescriptions;

  /// Returns a two-level map that on the first level contains the resolved
  /// table name, and on the second level the column name (or its alias).
  Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> toTableColumnMap();

  /// Returns a single-level map that maps the column name (or its alias) to the
  /// value returned on that position.
  Map<String, dynamic> toColumnMap();
}

/// The query result.
///
/// Rows can be accessed through the `[]` operator.
abstract class PostgreSQLResult implements List<PostgreSQLResultRow> {
  /// How many rows did this query affect?
  int get affectedRowCount;
  List<ColumnDescription> get columnDescriptions;
}
```

Could you show me how should be look empty result `PostgreSQLResult` set?

Comment: Null-safety doesn't mean never using `null`.  There are times when using `null` is appropriate, such as when you have no result to return.  Also compare to `Map.operator []`.  Just make `getResultFromCache` return a `PostgreSQLResult?` instead.

Comment: You alternatively could create your own class that derives from `PostgreSQLResult` and overrides its methods to return `0` for `affectedRowCount` and `[]` for `columnDescriptions`, but in general you might want to disintguish between a cached empty result and no cached result.